# Problem opening tkinter script via html page

Tags: python-3, php, tkinter

I am working on this project where I have Raspberry Pi 3 with full Raspbian (with GUI) connected to a 7" screen. I created a Python 3 script:

```py
// gui.py

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My Dash")
root.mainloop()
```

I then created a shell script to run this file:

```sh
// test.sh

python3 gui.py
```

Finally I created a PHP file to run this shell script:

```php
// run.php

<?php
    shell_exec("sudo /bin/bash test.sh");
?>
```

All these files reside in `/var/www/html` with `www-data` set as both the user and user-group. However, when you run the PHP file nothing happens.

I've tried redirecting errors to a log file and it gives me the following error:

> ```
> (tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0")
> ```

If I run the Python file directly in the terminal, it displays the GUI successfully.

Can TKinter scripts only be run from the terminal and not from a webpage? If so, is there some kind of workaround? I'm trying to develop a web application where you can fire off TKinter windows from buttons on the site.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot display GUI screens created with tkinter on a web page.  (Irrelevant but for completeness - You can display a web page in Tkinter though.)

Some of the functionality (widgets) of tkinter has been 'HTML-y-fied' by a package called tk_html_widgets available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/paolo-gurisatti/tk_html_widgets).  I've never tried this but it may simplify conversion.

If this does not give you the richness of your application screens, there are a few possible ways around this:

1. Create the screen using php etc and display it as a web page
2. [Embed the Python program](https://www.csestack.org/python-generate-html/) in HTML to create the screen.
3. Use the inbuilt web server for Python and [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)
4. Go full blown web development using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Other web development frameworks are available (e.g. web2py / Pyramid etc) for Python.

Comment: I dont want to open tkinter into html. I want a button on my page to run python file that has tkinter code.. As a separate window and not inside html page

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it by using ssh in php,
It's a little bit tricky but the idea is to send the following command before you execute your python script:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

this command will allow you to run a tkinter window from a remote shell.

So in order to send this command and run the script I used the phpsec library you can find it [here](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/master/phpseclib).
just clone it in your website folder and in your php script do:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('localhost');
if (!$ssh->login('YourSSH_Login', 'YourSSH_Password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('export DISPLAY=:0;python3 /pathToYourScript/YourScript.py');
```

Your script will now run on the server's current display.